# Error in building own kernel for ubuntu 20.04 with kernel 5.13

Tags: kernel, compiler

We are building own kernel image on the system ubuntu 20.04.4 and kernel version 5.13.0-40-generic and compiling kernel version is kwe-5.13.0 but get below error as follow.

```
  CC      /home/embed/workspace/Intel_atom/5_13_40/New_5.13/focal/debian/build/build-generic/tools/bpf/resolve_btfids/string.o
  CC      /home/embed/workspace/Intel_atom/5_13_40/New_5.13/focal/debian/build/build-generic/tools/bpf/resolve_btfids/ctype.o
  CC      /home/embed/workspace/Intel_atom/5_13_40/New_5.13/focal/debian/build/build-generic/tools/bpf/resolve_btfids/str_error_r.o
  LD      /home/embed/workspace/Intel_atom/5_13_40/New_5.13/focal/debian/build/build-generic/tools/bpf/resolve_btfids/resolve_btfids-in.o
  LINK     resolve_btfids
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/embed/workspace/Intel_atom/5_13_40/New_5.13/focal/debian/build/build-generic'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/embed/workspace/Intel_atom/5_13_40/New_5.13/focal'
touch /home/embed/workspace/Intel_atom/5_13_40/New_5.13/focal/debian/stamps/stamp-prepare-tree-generic
Debug: config-prepare-check-generic
check-config: /home/embed/workspace/Intel_atom/5_13_40/New_5.13/focal/debian/build/build-generic/.config: loading config
check-config: /home/embed/workspace/Intel_atom/5_13_40/New_5.13/focal/debian.hwe-5.13/config/annotations loading annotations
check-config: FAIL (n != -): CONFIG_KCSAN policy<{'amd64': '-', 'arm64': '-', 'armhf': '-', 'ppc64el': '-', 's390x': '-'}>
check-config: 11083/11084 checks passed -- exit 1
make: *** [debian/rules.d/4-checks.mk:25: config-prepare-check-generic] Error 1
```

please help me regarding this issue.

Comment: You seem to have a kernel configuration error in `/home/embed/workspace/Intel_atom/5_13_40/New_5.13/focal/debian/build/build-generic/.config`, something to do with which architecture you are compiling for.

Comment: I don't understand which change required in this file. any suggestion.

Comment: I don't know. Try looking through the file. Maybe look for `CONFIG_KCSAN` (which I do not have in mine).